# If $q$ is positive and $(q^{k+1} - 1)/({q^k}(q - 1)) < 5/4$ for all $k$, does it ever happen that $q > 5$ for some $k = K > 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

**Problem Statement**

> If $q$ is positive and $$\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{q^k}(q - 1)} < \frac{5}{4},$$
>   for all $k$, does it ever happen that $q > 5$ for some $k = K > 1$?

(For my purposes, it would suffice to consider $K \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.)

**My Attempts At Particular Values of $K$ (Using WolframAlpha)**

[$K = 5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(q%5E6%20-%201)%2F((q%5E5)(q%20-%201))%20%3C%205%2F4): $q > 4.99871835823626641$

[$K = 9$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(q%5E(10)%20-%201)%2F((q%5E9)(q%20-%201))%20%3C%205%2F4): $q > 4.9999979519924502095$

[$K = 13$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(q%5E(14)%20-%201)%2F((q%5E(13))(q%20-%201))%20%3C%205%2F4): $q > 4.9999999967231999721$

[$K = 17$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(q%5E(18)%20-%201)%2F((q%5E(17))(q%20-%201))%20%3C%205%2F4): $q > 4.9999999999947571200$

[$K = 21$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(q%5E(22)%20-%201)%2F((q%5E(21))(q%20-%201))%20%3C%205%2F4): $q > 4.9999999999999916114$

**"Conclusion"**

I conjecture that the answer to my question is *NO*, but I am currently unable to prove it.  Any helpful hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $q$ is greater than $1$ (since we are looking for $q$ greater than $5$). Then it follows that
$$q^{k+1}-1 \lt \frac{5}{4}(q^{k+1}-q^k)$$
$$4q^{k+1}-4 \lt 5(q^{k+1}-q^k)$$
$$5q^k-q^{k+1}-4 \lt 0$$
$$5-q-\frac{4}{q^k} \lt 0$$
$$5 \lt q+\frac{4}{q^k}$$
It seems that this will be true whenever $q \gt 5$, and for some values less than $5$ depending on the value of $k$. Is there some mistake here?

Comment: Oh whoops! Thanks for catching that error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I confirm that there is no mistake in the formulation of the problem.

Comment: Yep, no problem.

Comment: So if I take $\epsilon = 4/q^k > 0$, then $q > 5 - \epsilon$, so that $q > 5$ will not be attained.

Comment: Ummm... not necessarily. Just because $q \gt 5-\epsilon$ doesn't imply that $q$ cannot be greater than $5$. In fact, what I have shown is that $q$ can be and usually is greater than $5$. That's why I was wondering if I made a mistake - I seemed to have disproven your conjecture that seemed to be true.

Comment: Oops sorry. I meant that $5 - \epsilon < 5$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. In that sense, WolframAlpha will always return a value less than $5$ of a strict lower bound for $q$, thus proving my conjecture.

Comment: Oh, you meant as a lower bound. Yeah, I see what you mean now. Well, glad I could help (though it was mostly accidental)!